# Show the input RGB color

Tags: code-golf

Write a program that takes R, G, and B values as command arguments and then displays that color some way. It doesn't matter how, as long as at least 100 pixels have the color. Shortest code wins.

Comment: This would be improved a lot if you specified how much of the input colour should be displayed. Is just one pixel OK? I recommend you make it a requirement that the screen/window background colour (or the majority of the screen/window) be displayed in the input colour. Even so, it's rather simple.

Comment: Is `COLOR` command of Windows prompt valid? It has only 16 possibilities of color from 0 to F

Comment: I should win it!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### JavaScript, 25

```
document.bgColor=prompt()
```

You'll have to specify the three components in hexadecimal. This is code golf, so no commas or whitespace.

Comment: Hexadecimal: cheeky, but I like it!

Comment: Wouldn't you need a `'#'+`, then?

Comment: @Doorknob: HTML is too cool to choke on malformed input: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318911/why-does-html-think-chucknorris-is-a-color

Comment: I should win it!

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript, 57 characters

```javascript
document.body.setAttribute('bgcolor','rgb('+prompt()+')')
```

Enter the RGB values in the prompt input box, comma separated.

(I feel so dirty, using `bgcolor` :O )

Comment: `bgcolor`? That really brings me back to a simpler time...

Answer (score 4):

### xterm: 18 bytes

```
xterm -bg \#$1$2$3
```

Input the color as three 1- or 2-digit hex numbers, e.g., if this command is in the file "xterm.sh", then

```
./xterm.sh ff 00 00
./xterm.sh f 0 0
```

opens a terminal window with a red background.

If you prefer, you can omit the blanks between the components:

```
./xterm.sh f00
```

The "-bg" option is not available in some old versions of xterm.  It's missing from version 271 but present in versions 215, 251, 261, and 297.

Answer (score 2):

## Bash, 69

```
read c;set $c;printf '\e]4;1;rgb:'"$1"'/'"$2"'/'"$3"'\e\\\e[31mc\e[m'
```

Partially stolen from [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/103909/72471).

Just input your values in hex (e.g. FF 00 00).

Tested on `xterm-256color`.

## Bash, 43

```
printf '\e]4;1;rgb:FF/00/00\e\\\e[31mc\e[m'
```

Here you have to input the values yourself.

**Edit**: For 100 Pixels+ Just choose font-size infinite :D.

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript in PCCG, 65 <s>105</s>

**Edit 2** shortened as suggested by @manatwork

**Edit**
Thanks @blender

```
question.style.background='#'+prompt('R G B').split(' ').join('')
```

Just for fun

Comment: You can replace `document.getElementById('question')` with just `question`.

Comment: You can assign to the `background` property. (As a side effect will reset `backgroundImage` and alike, but not a problem in this case.)

Answer (score 1):

### Bash/sh + ImageMagick: 28 bytes

```
display -size 96 xc:\#$1$2$3
```

Input the color as three 1- or 2-digit hex numbers, with or without whitespace between them.

Comment: I was thinking xsetroot -solid '#xyz', but this is better.  (And the effect of xsetroot is only visible if you aren't using a desktop environment that covers the X11 root window with a window showing a background, rather than drawing the background on the root window directly.)

Comment: xterm is shorter: "xterm -bg \#$1$2$3"; I'll post that as a new answer.

Answer (score 1):

**C# WPF : 54**

```
new Windows(){Background=Color.FromArgb(RGB);}.Show();
```

Answer (score 1):

## Postscript <del>61</del> 56

Fills the graphics window with the color, components as decimals in the range 0..1.

```
ARGUMENTS{cvr}forall setrgbcolor clippath fill showpage
```

Run using ghostscript's `--` option which enables argument processing.

```
gs -- rgb.ps .9 .2 .2
```

Answer (score 0):

## Java, 215

```
import java.awt.*;class C{public static void main(String[]a){Frame f=new Frame();f.setSize(9,99);f.setBackground(new Color(Integer.parseInt(a[0]),Integer.parseInt(a[1]),Integer.parseInt(a[2])));f.setVisible(true);}}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Tcl/Tk, 15

```
. co -bg #$argv
```

## Tcl/Tk, 22

```
. configure -bg #$argv
```

If called with

```
wish show_color.tcl 6666AA
```

one gets

[image]

## Tcl/Tk, 27

```
grid [canvas .c -bg #$argv]
```

If called with

```
wish show_color.tcl 6666AA
```

one gets

[image]